# Create a list from a big matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I'm trying to create a list from a big matrix as following:

```
  A = matrix(rnorm(500000*10), nrow = 500000, ncol = 10)
    B = list()
    begin = Sys.time()
    for (i in 1: nrow(A)){
      B[[i]] = A[i,]
    }
    end = Sys.time()
    end - begin
```

However it takes too much time. Any idea to optimize this code? Thank you.

Comment: `B<-split(A, c(row(A)))`

Answer (score 0):

Sweet and simple

```
B = as.list(data.frame(t(A)))
```